# remove .php in URLs if users enters .php on the browser

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I already successfully removed the .php file extension by configuring my .htaccess file, my problem here is that when a user types on .php on the URL, I wanted the user to be redirected incase they type in the .php on the URL. So for example, my original URL is

```
http://mysite.com/home
```

Sometimes, the user will type like this
`http://mysite.com/home.php`, so in this case, I wanted to redirect them to a url without .php, so it should be `http://mysite.com/home`

Another example would be if a URL has a parameter, so for example:

```
http://mysite.com/home.php?id=1&uid=100
```

I want the user to be redirected to `http://mysite.com/home?id=1&uid=100`

Any ideas how to do this?
Your help will be greatly appreciated and rewarded! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to match against the actual request instead of the URI because your other rules are rewriting the URI. So something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php(\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

So if someone types: `http://mysite.com/some/path/home.php`, the browser will get redirected (thus changing the URL in the address bar) to `http://mysite.com/some/path/home`.

If you only want to do this for php files in your document root (e.g. `/home.php` and **not** `/some/path/to/home.php`) then tweak the regex:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^/]+)\.php(\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Oh, it does work, but the problem is if the url has a parameters so for example: http://mysite.com/home.php?id=1&uid=100, it does not work. You have any idea? :)

Comment: @ElsonSolano Yeah, you need a `\?` at the end. See the edit, the end of the request match needs to be `(\?|\ |$)` to include a possible query string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.htaccess`.  Here's some code I currently use on my sites which replace `/page.php` to `/page/`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]
```

Put this in a file called `.htaccess` - No name, the 'extension' in this case, is the file itself.  Save and upload to the server in your `public_html` folder.  Or whatever your base/public directory is.

The last line in this code is the one that helps you, it replaces any file ending in `.php` file to a file with a `/` at the end, as explained above.  Line 2 and 3 forward `http://domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com`.  I don't know about you but I think it looks better like that.

Comment: would this redirect the user to a non .php URL incase they type in a .php on the URL?

Comment: If they typed in `index.php` or `file.php`, it would still direct them to the `.php` file.  The code above does not direct them to a non `.php` file, it is the same file but the URL is different.

Comment: Oh, I already solved that on my current .htaccess configuration, what I want is to redirect them. Anyway, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this at the top of your file:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.php')!==false){
$good_path = str_replace($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.php','');
header('Location: '.$good_path);
}
```

Better to use regex to check for extension, but this is a quick example only to get you started.